# UICollectionView created programmatically doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm making a horizontal picker by using a `UICollectionView`.  It's simple enough: A `UIView` with a `UICollectionView` created programmatically, using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with one section, scrolling set to horizontal.  It appears onscreen, complete with the correct data in the correct cells.  But it doesn't scroll---in fact it doesn't respond to user interaction at all.

Here's the initializer for the view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andItemData:(NSArray *)itemData
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _itemData = itemData;

        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
        [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(kCellWidth, kCellHeight)];
        [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.f];
        [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.f];

        _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[self frame] collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
        [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
        [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
        [_collectionView setBounces:NO];
        [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HorizontalPickerCell"];
        [self addSubview:_collectionView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I tried programmatically setting `UserInteractionEnabled` to `YES`, but that didn't make any difference (nor should it have, since `UserInteractionEnabled` is set to `YES` by default).  FWIW, the collection view uses standard `UICollectionViewCell`s with `UILabel`s added to their `contentView`s as subviews.

Any thought as to why this isn't scrolling?  Any and all help much appreciated.

Comment: I dropped your code into a new project, and it did scroll.  Are you sure you have enough data to make it need to scroll?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, more than enough.  itemData has 21 NSNumbers in it (from 0 to 100, going up by 5s). I'm glad it worked for you, though, and it means my problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Set bounce NO ? Are you Crazy ? /joke

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this turned out to be both dumb on my part and easy to fix.  I set the frame of the collection view to its parent view's `frame` rather than its `bounds`.  This caused all sorts of autolayout issues and resulted in touch events simply not registering.  All fixed now.