# iOS UICollectionView not scrolling when cell is touched

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I've created a simple grid based UICollectionView but I'm having trouble with the scrolling. If I touch the view itself rather than a cell within it then it seems to scroll correctly but if I touch one of the cells and try to scroll then nothing happens. This is a bit of an issue, as I basically want the grid of cells to completely fill the view, and when the view is filled like that there is nowhere to touch that will actually make it scroll! I guess the easiest way to describe what I'm trying to achieve is a table view but with two columns of cells rather than one.

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that talks about this issue and I've tried various combinations of "user interaction enabled" settings etc.

One final thing, I do require the cells to respond to a single tap touch (basically to toggle them on and off) so I don't want to completely disable them responding to touches.

Comment: Have you added a tapgesturerecognizer or anything similar to the cells?

Comment: No, I haven't added any gesture recognisers to the cells. They're pretty basic with just a text label and an image added programmatically.

Comment: Does it respond to taps? i.e. does it run didSelectItem...

Comment: Yep, tapping works and correctly runs the code in didSelectItem.

Comment: Hmm... are you sure you're scrolling in the correct direction? Can you NSLog the frame of the CollectionView?

Comment: Yep, definitely scrolling in the correct direction. As I said, if I touch outside of a cell it scrolls as expected, it's only when I touch inside of a cell that it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm... never seen that myself. The only time it has happened is if I had a button on there or was consuming the touch in the cell. Next question, are you overriding `touchesBegan` or any other touch method in the cell?

Comment: Nope, the only code relating to the cell is the code for actually constructing it and a couple of functions for setting it as toggled on or off.

Comment: Hmm... very odd. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698244/uicollectionview-created-programmatically-doesnt-scroll